# SQL Update with results from another Table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to update the qty field on my table products with the following query. 
This query is returning me the desired numbers in Qty field.

```
SELECT e.Prod_name, e.Prod_number,
  (SUM(e.Qty) - SUM(g.Qty)) Qty
FROM Products_Invoices e JOIN (
    SELECT product_number, SUM(qty) Qty
    FROM SoldItemsCalc
    GROUP BY product_number
  ) g ON e.Prod_number = g.product_number
GROUP BY Prod_number, Prod_name
order by Prod_name
```

How can I use this query and update the values where the product_number matches

I don't mind if you change the query... Just need to update the qty values

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do it this way:

```
with toupdate as (
    SELECT e.Prod_name, e.Prod_number, (SUM(e.Qty) - SUM(g.Qty)) Qty
    FROM Products_Invoices e JOIN (
         SELECT product_number, SUM(qty) Qty
         FROM SoldItemsCalc
         GROUP BY product_number
        ) g ON e.Prod_number = g.product_number
    GROUP BY Prod_number, Prod_name
   )
update t
    set qty = toupdate.qty
    from toupdate
    where t.prod_nubmer = toupdate.prod_number
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure your qty is producing your desired results?  You're doing a SUM in your subquery and then doing another SUM in your outer query.  That is probably messing your numbers up.  Here is a slight variation of @Gordon's good answer -- this is updating the Product table using the qty I think you want:

```
with toupdate as (
    SELECT e.Prod_name, e.Prod_number, (SUM(e.Qty) - g.Qty) Qty
    FROM Products_Invoices e JOIN (
         SELECT product_number, SUM(qty) Qty
         FROM SoldItemsCalc
         GROUP BY product_number
        ) g ON e.Prod_number = g.product_number
    GROUP BY Prod_number, Prod_name, g.Qty
   )
update p
    set qty = t.qty
    from products p join toupdate t on p.prod_number = t.prod_number;
```

And here is the Fiddle with the example: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/42c80/1

There are 2 records in the Product_Invoices table which SUM to 150.  And 2 records in the SoldItemsCalc table which sum to 25.  Using your query, the overall result changes to 100 when I imagine you want 125.

BTW -- using the CTE above will work for SQL Server 2005 and higher.  If you need to support SQL Server 2000, then use this version:

```
update p
    set qty = t.qty
    from products p join (
      SELECT e.Prod_name, e.Prod_number, (SUM(e.Qty) - g.Qty) Qty
      FROM Products_Invoices e JOIN (
         SELECT product_number, SUM(qty) Qty
         FROM SoldItemsCalc
         GROUP BY product_number
        ) g ON e.Prod_number = g.product_number
    GROUP BY Prod_number, Prod_name, g.Qty) t on p.prod_number = t.prod_number;
```

Comment: I get the same results with your query too...
I double checked my results and they seems to be fine... Thank you

Comment: @Barlet -- ok, but be careful -- see this fiddle for what I mean: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0cc74/1 -- Best of luck!

Comment: @Barlet -- basically if you have more than a single record in your Products_Invoices table with the same prod_number, you're Summed SoldItemsCalc table will be wrong (multiplier of the number of records in the other table).  No worries though if your query returns what you want -- just wanted to make you aware :)